# Login page in PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am a learner in phonegap and i have done a simple login page using html, css and Javascript.

I have two edit texts for entering user id and password.
I have not written the onclick function for the button click.

Here is the login.html code:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>  
    <script>

    function onLoad(){
                document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
             }

    function onDeviceReady(){
                navigator.notification.alert("PhoneGap is working");
             }

    function validate(){

      var name = document.getElementById("usrname").value;
      var pwd = document.getElementById("usrpswd").value;

      if(name=="aaa" && pwd=="aaa"){
          localStorage.name = name;
          localStorage.password = pwd;

          alert(name);
          window.open("display.html");
        }else{
          alert("Error capturing data");
       }
   }

   function reset(){
      document.getElementById("usrname").value = "";
      var pwd = document.getElementById("usrpswd").value = "";
   }

</script>

 <meta name="viewport", initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
</head>

<body onload="onLoad();">

<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a" data-id="mainHeader"><h3 style="width:480px;">Login</h3></div> 
 <div class="bg" id="login">
     <form name="login" id="formlogin" method="post" action="" accept-charset="utf-8" style="background:color="#cb1f72">

       <br/>
       <br/>
       <br/>
       <div class="inputcredentials">
            <label>USER NAME:</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="usrname"/>
            <br />
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <label>PASSWORD:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="usrpswd" style="margin-left:6px"/>
            <br /> 
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <button class="submit" name="submit" onclick="validate()">Submit</button>
            <button class="reset" name="reset" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </form> 
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

When i click on the buttons the data what i have entered in the edit text gets reset.
What is the reason behind this?

Comment: show full code what you have tried.

Comment: what is issues here tell

Comment: Upon clicking submit, it will perform the action you have defined in the form-element (<form>)

Comment: <form name="login" id="formlogin" method="get" action="" accept-charset="utf-8" style="background:color="#cb1f72"> This is my form element and i have not defined any action here.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that your form is submitting. This will result in a page reload.